# Why does unity skip my start screen scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm a beginner in unity and I made a game with multiple levels and a start screen. Not finished yet. I added the start screen and the levels to the build settings, and pressed build. But when I run it, it skips the start screen. Even when I set it as the last scene, it skips.

Build settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHQ95.png

Start screen scene: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJIaI.png

Comment: Can you show us the levels in the build settings please? Start screen should be your first scene (index 0)

Comment: I added a image, and my starter scene has the build index 0. But it also skips when its the last scene.

Comment: On your image it has the index 5. Can you show us your start screen scene?

Comment: Ooooh, sorry. Just realized, it was from when i tried if it works when it is the last scene (didn't). But I edited the picture and added another one.

Comment: Ok so I think something is loading your next level directly at the start of your start scene. So start scene is here but so shortly that you can't see it. Check where you are loading the next scene, maybe it is in the start method of a script

Comment: Thanks!!! I made a start button with a script attached to load level 1. But i used void Start()

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things to check when using a start scene :

- Make sure that it is in the levels build settings
- Make sure that it is at the index 0
- Check the script responsible of loading the next level. Here, a Start function was doing it, so the start screen was loaded but immediatly loaded the next level.